# How to solve TemplateDoesNotExist at /account

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I am getting `TemplateDoesNotExist at /account` issues in my website, all code is working perfect on my `localhost` but this issue is coming on server, please let me know where is the mistake.

Here is my `urls.py` file...

```
app_name='account'

urlpatterns = [
    path('account', views.accounts, name='useraccount'),
]
```

here is my `views.py` file...

```
def accounts(request):
    return render(request, 'account/account.html')
```

my `account.html` file path is this....`account(app name)/templates/account/account.html`

and this is link...

```
<li>
  <a href="{% url 'account:useraccount' %}">Account</a>
</li>
```

here is the value of TEMPLATES in `setting.py` file...

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            'mainpage.context_processors.context_categories',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

Comment: Can you add the value of `TEMPLATES` settings variable?

Comment: please check my updated question

Comment: Double check that `account` is in your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting. Look carefully at the full `TemplateDoesNotExist` error message (when `DEBUG=True`) - it lists the directories that Django tried, which might identify what the problem is.